# Copy and rename multiple files in one step by txt list

Tags: unix, batch-rename

I have list of files what I have to rename. There is no sequence or pattern in renaming therefore I use a .txt files to do it. I can rename and copy files in separate step but I would like to combine this process into one step. The challenging part, why I am going to do it in one step, is some source file should be renamed (and copied) to multiple files.

Example:

source-file-1.jpg -> renamed-file-1.jpg

source-file-1.jpg -> renamed-file-2.jpg

source-file-1.jpg -> renamed-file-3.jpg

I use following xargs commends to rename and copy files.

> xargs -a copy.txt cp -t /new-folder
>
> xargs -a rename.txt -n 2 mv

It is possible co combine these commands? I hope if I copy files first I could achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

`/bin/cp` allows you to specify the target filename as well as the target directory.

So

```
cp source-file-1.jpg new-folder/renamed-file-1.jpg
cp source-file-1.jpg new-folder/renamed-file-2.jpg
cp source-file-1.jpg new-folder/renamed-file-3.jpg
```

will both copy and rename the files in one step.